# Define a matrix $V$ such that its $(i,j)$-th entry is $\langle r_i,r_j \rangle$. Show that $V$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, inner-products

Let $\{r_i\}$ be a finite list of independent vectors. Denote the inner product of two vectors as $\langle r_i,r_j \rangle$. Define a matrix $V$ such that its $(i,j)$-th entry is $\langle r_i,r_j \rangle$. Show that $V$ is invertible.

I came up with this problem myself while studying projections.

My attempt is as follows:

If $V$  is not invertible, we may write a row (assume its $k$-th row) of $V$ as linear combination of some other rows :

$$(\langle r_k,r_1 \rangle,\langle r_k,r_2 \rangle,\dots)=a \cdot (\langle r_{l_1},r_1 \rangle,\langle r_{l_1},r_2 \rangle,\dots)+b\cdot(\langle r_{l_2},r_1 \rangle,\langle r_{l_2},r_2 \rangle,\dots)+\cdots$$

$$\Rightarrow \quad z:=(r_k-ar_{l_1}-br_{l_2}-\cdots)\perp r_j\ , \quad \forall j$$
by entry-wise comparison where $a,b,...\neq 0$.

So $z \in \text{span}(r_1,...)^\perp$ but $z \in \text{span}(r_1,...)$. This implies $z=0$, 
$$\implies r_k=ar_{l_1}+br_{l_2}+\cdots$$
contradicting independence of $\{r_i\}$.

Comment: The proof looks good -- are you looking for other solutions?

Comment: @user125932 I'm not sure the proof is correct. Since this result is important to me, I figured it is better to ask here. Other solutions are welcome of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. It is notable that your matrix is sometimes called a [Gramian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix).  The wikipedia page provides an [alternative proof of your fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix#Derivation_of_positive-semidefiniteness), which you might want to take a look at.

Comment: Tanks. I thought this must have been studied because what I was doing is just to generalize projection matrix beyond Euclidean case.